# Reference where clause in instead of update trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Is there a way to reference the where clause in instead of update trigger?

** More info **

I'm trying to get around this issue:
[Modify update statement includes primary key in trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422862/modify-update-statement-includes-primary-key-in-trigger).

This wonder product will try to update rows that have changed or that may not even exist. Since I don't need/care about the existing data if I could modify the where clause to be more generic the update would run and I could move on.

Comment: What where clause? The where clause of the insert select? Perhpas you should show us the data you are interested in and how you want to manipulate it in the trigger so we have a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: @HLGEM -- As in `Update T set col1 = xxx where col1 = yyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the deleted table shows the data you selected with the where clause, so if you know the where clause is on column 1 you know the values you asked for? But directly know what is inthe where clause, no. The only data you have avaliable in a trigger is the data in the table before and after the update statment.

Maybe if you expressed what you want to do inteh trigger it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this particular template to update data, which you've mentioned in a comment:

```
UPDATE T SET col1 = xxx WHERE col1 = yyy
```

that is, if you update some column based on its current value, then, I think, it will be right to say that yes, you *can* 'access the WHERE clause'.

Actually what you will be accessing then are the so called 'magic tables', `DELETED` and `INSERTED`, which hold values, respectively before and after update. The values before update, in particular, are those very ones referenced by the WHERE clause of the above UPDATE statement.